# Vertx RxJava Operator iteration not filtering the content

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, vert.x, rx-java3

I am reading the content from file, I put some name into the file with new line separator but while reading the file by vertx file-system I am not able to provide the required filter. every-time it print all the data of file.

Here is the code snippet :-

```
vertx.fileSystem().open("data.txt", new OpenOptions(), handler -> {
                final AsyncFile asyncFile = handler.result();
                final Observable<Buffer> observable = asyncFile.toObservable();
                observable.subscribe(item -> {
                    final String[] split = item.toString().split("\n\r");
                    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(split);
                    final Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromIterable(list);
                    stringObservable
                            .filter(name -> name.toString().startsWith("R"))
                            .take(2)
                            .subscribe(str -> System.out.println(str), err -> System.out.println(err), () -> System.out.println("Inner loop completed"));


                }, error -> System.out.println(error), () -> System.out.println("Completed !!!"));
            });
```

Internal observable I used after i find out the above observable have all the data of file in one go.

Comment: Can you provide input text file as previous answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Pendula file is containing some random names in every new line like Rat \n Ravat \n Romania \n India \n Africa, please \n as new line

Comment: My answer works correctly with that input file - it outputs `Rat\nRavat\nCompleted`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet actually works fine for me if I split on "\n" instead of "\n\r". If you're having issues with it printing everything, my guess is that the first character in the whole file is "R", and then you don't actually have "\n\r" anywhere in the file. So when you try to split, you end up with just one large String that has the whole file in it.

That said, you can simplify this code significantly by using `rxOpen` instead of `open`, avoiding the nesting of subscribes, and simplifying how you turn the `Buffer` into an `Observable` that emits each line in the `Buffer`.

Also note that I used [`RecordParser`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/reactivex/core/parsetools/RecordParser.html) to split the contents of the file into tokens using  the "\n" character as a delimiter. Just directly turning `AsyncFile` into an `Observable<Buffer>` using `toObservable()` could result in a `Buffer`s that cut off partway through a line, which would screw up your parsing.

So putting it all together:

```java
vertx.fileSystem().rxOpen("data.txt", new OpenOptions())
    .flatMapObservable(af -> RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", af).toObservable())
    .map(Buffer::toString)
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("R"))
    .take(2)
    .subscribe(System.out::println, System.err::println, () -> System.out.println("Completed"));
```

You go from 13 lines to 6.

Comment: Are you sure that `buff` contains the whole file, so you do not need to handle a situation when you have loaded just part of the line and `split` is not going to work in this case?

Comment: @skywall Ah, yes, I think you're right, a large enough file will likely be split into multiple Buffers. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @skywall I updated my answer to account for multiple Buffers being returned for one file.

Comment: @dano, No help still getting the same response none of the operator is working

Comment: @RavatTailor You need to provide a sample data.txt that isn't working or something then, because the code in your question, and the code in my answer, both work fine for me using the dummy data I came up with for data.txt.